# PHP PDO Problem

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having trouble setting up PDO in my website framework.

I open my connection in "system.php" which is included at the beginning of every page with this code here

```
try {   
 $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass, 
        array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));  
}  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

and on the same file (system.ph) I call this below it:

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT value FROM settings WHERE type="theme"');  
 $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
 while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  
  define('THEME', 'themes/'.$row['value'].'/'); 
 }
```

Which works perfectly!

However, when I call the same query as above on `"default.php"` (which is included in the file) it comes back with:

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: DBH in /pages/default.php on line 15

    Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
 in /pages/default.php on line 15
```

What am I doing wrong here?

`default.php`

```
<?php 
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT value FROM settings WHERE type="theme"'); 
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
while($row = $STH->fetch()) { echo $row['value']; } 
?>
```

Comment: It's the exact same snippet.

<?php

$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT value FROM settings WHERE type="theme"');  
 $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
 while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  
  echo $row['value'];
 }  

?>

Comment: does it work if you wrap the default.php code in a function definition, and call that function in the main script?

Comment: Just tried it again - nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is inside a function add

```
  global $DBH;
```

in the function before calling the query() function.

Comment: No difference Notice: Undefined variable: DBH in pages/default.php on line 15

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in pages/default.php on line 15

Comment: Is there two 'default.php' files? Remove all content from default.php and run it. Ensure that it is the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that file isn't getting included in default.php for whatever reason. Is there a boot strapper someplace that does the including for you before `default.php` is loaded?

Also, make sure that you're not getting an error on the path that loads `default.php`. It seems to me that `$DBH` would be undefined if there were an exception. Are you using output buffering someplace that might be cleared before you can see the echoing of the exception? You may want to consider logging your exceptions to a text file instead so that output buffering doesn't prevent you from seeing the errors which are occurring.

Comment: My structure is set up so - 

Index.php loads System.php
System.php loads Theme.php
Theme.php loads Default.php

(Default being in another dir where all the "content" is stored)

Comment: Added comments to my answer regarding `$DBH` being undefined if an exception occurs. ^